# Font asset not found fonts/.ttf in Xamarin forms after updating Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Yesterday I updated vs2019 to v16.6.0 from v16.5.4. Now I am facing an issue of **Font asset not found fonts/.ttf** in Xamarin forms android app. App worked really well before the update. This issue poped up after the updation. If i clean and rebuild project then app works but in the next run this RuntimeException pop up again. I need to clean and rebuild the project again.

Log..

```
05-27 16:17:21.713 W/monodroid-assembly(22450): typemap: unable to find mapping to a managed type from Java type 'com/android/internal/policy/PhoneLayoutInflater'
05-27 16:17:21.715 W/monodroid-assembly(22450): typemap: unable to find mapping to a managed type from Java type 'android/support/v4/app/FragmentManagerImpl'
05-27 16:17:21.731 D/Mono    (22450): Requesting loading reference 8 (of 20) of Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll
05-27 16:17:21.731 D/Mono    (22450): Loading reference 8 of Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
05-27 16:17:21.731 D/Mono    (22450): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android[0x7f671f7300] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat[0x7f6716a000]: 5
**Java.Lang.RuntimeException:** 'Font asset not found fonts/Questrial-Regular.ttf'
```

App.xaml

```
            <OnPlatform x:Key="Lato-Regular" x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="Raleway-Regular" Android="fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf#Lato-Regular" />
            <OnPlatform x:Key="Questrial-Regular" x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="Questrial-Regular" Android="fonts/Questrial-Regular.ttf#Questrial-Regular" />
            <OnPlatform x:Key="OpenSans-Regular" x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="Raleway-Regular" Android="fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf#OpenSans-Regular" />
            <OnPlatform x:Key="Roboto-Medium" x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="Roboto-Medium" Android="fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf#Roboto-Medium" />
            <OnPlatform x:Key="NumberFontFamily" x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="sans-serif" Android="sans-serif"  />
```

Comment: If you are 100% sure that it worked before the update and that the update itself broke the build/functionality, then the proper approach is to report an issue to Microsoft/VS team.

Comment: Yes after the update.ok

Comment: Some one already posted here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1045818/after-update-vs-2019-xamarin-app-debug-throws-exce.html